# Script Uncommitted data from table using SMO

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I have a C# win form application which has a facility to backup databases **with data** to a script file while the application running.

I used following code to script the database using `SMO`;

```
public StringCollection GenerateDatabaseScript(string databaseName)
    {
        //Validate database name goes here  

        StringCollection dbScript = new StringCollection();

        //Create db connection                
        sqlDataAccess.DBConnect(databaseName); //Custom class to do SQL data operations (sqlDataAccess)

        //Create server and database objects
        var serverConn = new ServerConnection(sqlDataAccess.Connection);
        var dbServer = new Server(serverConn);
        var database = dbServer.Databases[databaseName];

        //Set script database options here
        //--

        //Set script database tables option here
        //--

        //Script database creation
        //I also use a method 'ScriptObjectWithBatchDelimiter' to add GO delimiter for each command manually.
        dbScript.AddRange(ScriptObjectWithBatchDelimiter(database.Script(dbScriptingOptions)).ToArray());

        //Set focus to new db                
        dbScript.Add(string.Format("USE [{0}]", databaseName));
        dbScript.Add("GO");

        foreach (Table table in database.Tables)
        {
            //Skip scripting system tables
            if (table.IsSystemObject)
                continue;

            //Script table
            dbScript.AddRange(ScriptObjectWithBatchDelimiter(table.EnumScript(tableScriptingOptions)).ToArray());
        }

        return dbScript;
    }
```

Problem occurs in this line when encountering a table in the database data is <s>not committed</s> `ROWLOCK`;

```
table.EnumScript(tableScriptingOptions)
```

The problem is how can I script data with `READUNCOMMITTED`? Is there any properties that I can set to achieve this?
The same question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041738/can-i-force-sql-smo-to-use-read-uncommitted-isolation), but the only answer provided not suitable.

**UPDATE**: Following code is tried (assumed with the Isolation part in the name) but, still not working.

```
database.SetSnapshotIsolation(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this:

`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`

msdn: *"Specifies that statements can read rows that have been modified by other transactions but not yet committed."*

so wrap your scripting work inside a transaction with Isolation Level "ReadUncommited".

this is a good example how to use transactions in c#:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ha4240h(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: so that's why you should visit the link! there you can see how to set a proper isolation level in C#!

Comment: OK. I'm looking in to it. Thanks.